# How to get the related field of a related field in Django REST Framework serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Imagine having three Django Models:

```
class A:
  Susu = models.CharField()
  # props...

class B:
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  Bar = models.CharField()
  # props...

class C:
  b = models.ForeignKey(B)
  c_prop
  # props...
```

I'd like to write a serializer for `C` objects, such that they are represented as

```
{
    "c_prop": "Foo",
    "b" : {
        "Bar": "Agu"
    },
    "a" : {
        "Susu", "Jaja"
    }
}
```

i.e. the foreign key of the `B` class is representated at the same level of nesting as the `B` object (instead of "within" B)

I have these serializers:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = ("Susu", )

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = B
    fields = ("a", )

class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer
    
    class Meta:
      model = C
      fields = ('c_prop', 'b', 'a', ) # <-- How to get the 'a' here (not just the PK of 'a' but the nested object representation?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` like that

```
a = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_a(self,obj):
    a = A.objects.filter(b__c=obj)
    return ASerializer(a, many=True).data
```